# mysqld stops right after starting because of corrupted tables (disk full + hardware reboot) - how to fix it?

Tags: mysql, debian

I'm dumb, I did the stupidest thing I could.
On one of my servers, the SSD was full and I wasn't aware of it.

The high-traffic website became working really slow, then started displaying errors, because even the database couldn't save new rows.

Before I figured what's going on, I performed a hard reboot. And then the mysqld service wasn't be able to start.

I started to delete some non important files (it turned out 80% of the space was trash), so now I have 80% of free space.

**Unfortunately, every time I try to run "service mysqld restart" or start, it starts and then stops immediately.**

My configuration:
- Debian 7.5 + DirectAdmin (Apache, MySQL),
- The database is huge and includes both MyISAM and InnoDB tables.

I tried to make an export, but cannot run mysqldump without working mysqld service.

I copied my tables from /usr/local/mysql/data and also have a backup, but in SQL format - so I cannot import it. 
But the best option is to run current tables, because the backup is old.

**I've tried so far:**

- myisamchk -r -v *.MYI
- Setting "innodb_force_recovery=3" (first I tried 1 and 2)
- Many hard reboots and all services restarts
- Change name of the corrupted database folder, but then I've seen errors in my log (couldn't find table files etc.)

MySQL log doesn't explain anything:

```
150813 15:48:13 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/ns390143.pid ended
150813 15:48:21 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
2015-08-13 15:48:21 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.12 started; log sequence number 28646291749
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Binlog end
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2015-08-13 15:48:21 2954 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2015-08-13 15:48:23 2954 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 28646291759
2015-08-13 15:48:23 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2015-08-13 15:48:23 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2015-08-13 15:48:23 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2015-08-13 15:48:23 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2015-08-13 15:48:23 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2015-08-13 15:48:23 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2015-08-13 15:48:23 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2015-08-13 15:48:23 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2015-08-13 15:48:23 2954 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2015-08-13 15:48:23 2954 [Note]
```

**My questions are:**

1. How to fix it? And is it possible?
2. If not, how can I import .sql file backup?

Comment: did u by chance delete usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys ?

Comment: No, I didn't, for sure. For what that file is responsible?

Comment: did u check if the file is still there? do you have access to the commandline? then u can run the database interactive to see what happens

Comment: the logifile clearly states whats up. 2 seconds of googling found this http://askubuntu.com/questions/102875/mysql-5-5-starts-and-then-instantly-stops

Comment: The file is not there, I didn't change the config, so it should be fine. I googled this topic before and tried to copy this file from the "english" directory, then it wasn't solving anything, just the error message was gone. Now I tried to add the directory to the config file and it started up, but the website still doesn't start and phpMyAdmin throws "#2002 - No such file or directory. The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).". But at least I was able to do a backup from mysqldump!

Comment: In other words, I can connect from my shell, but not from the website (PHP), even from phpMyAdmin. Credentials are the same. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

It was an error with the config.

The correct path to MYSQL socket in Directadmin my.conf is:
/tmp/mysql.sock

Also bind-address is:
127.0.0.1

It's working now!!!

Answer (score 0):

The file is not there, I didn't change the config, so it should be fine. I googled this topic before and tried to copy this file from the "english" directory, then it wasn't solving anything, just the error message was gone.

Now I tried to add the directory to the config file and it started up, but the website still doesn't start and phpMyAdmin throws "#2002 - No such file or directory. The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).".

But at least I was able to do a backup from mysqldump!

Current log:

```
150813 16:41:34 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/ns390143.pid ended
150813 16:41:37 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
2015-08-13 16:41:38 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-08-13 16:41:38 20975 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-08-13 16:41:38 20975 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-08-13 16:41:38 20975 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-08-13 16:41:38 20975 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-08-13 16:41:38 20975 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-08-13 16:41:38 20975 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-08-13 16:41:38 20975 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-08-13 16:41:38 20975 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-08-13 16:41:38 20975 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-08-13 16:41:38 20975 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-08-13 16:41:38 20975 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-08-13 16:41:38 20975 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.12 started; log sequence number 28646292851
2015-08-13 16:41:38 20975 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2015-08-13 16:41:38 20975 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2015-08-13 16:41:38 20975 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2015-08-13 16:41:38 20975 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-08-13 16:41:38 20975 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.12'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
20975
```

What to do now if it still working only partially?

Comment: It looks like my.cnf file has been reset... Does anyone has the default DirectAdmin's my.cnf file?

Comment: I can connect from my shell, but not from the website (PHP), even from phpMyAdmin. Credentials are the same. What's wrong?